# Mod query in MongoDriver

Tags: java, mongodb

I try to get the result from mongoDB based on MOD. I prepared Query like below:

```
{ "customerInfo.Number" : { "$mod" : [ 10 , 1]}}
```

This query not returning any records from MongoDB. Please let me know anything I am doing wrong.

JSON Structure:

```
{
  "customerInfo" : {
        "Number" : "89786864361", 
        "ACode" : "8465283639", 
        "BCode" : "1", 
        "CCode" : "638368262782"
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave Sample values it is not exactly same values i query

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why you are not getting the results are

1. the value of Number is string `"89786864362"`, change it to a number.
2. `89786864362%10 == 2`, and you are doing `"$mod" : [ 10 , 1]`. If you change to `"$mod" : [ 10 , 2]` you will get the result.

Comment: Now you editted the value to "89786864361" ? Now your query should work. @Narshimha

Comment: Thanks for answer. off course it should work but unfortunately it is not giving any results that what  i am thinking why it is not working i am using java-mongo-driver-3.2.2. is their any jar version difference

Comment: I have tried your query.
db.getCollection('test_utf').find({ "customerInfo.Number" : { "$mod" : [ 10 , 1]}})


I am getting the result 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a005bbdcaa314d749bd5be1"),
    "customerInfo" : {
        "Number" : NumberLong(89786864361),
        "ACode" : "8465283639",
        "BCode" : "1",
        "CCode" : "638368262782"
    }
}

Comment: I understood why it is not returning values  my value is in String. Thnaks

Comment: Welcome. You can mark my answer as correct ans and one up vote for my work. :)